# In Flex, is there a Spark equivalent of DividedBox?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-spark, halo

I need a kind of `DividedBox` with Flex (4.6). This is a component where two groups of components are separated by a bar that can be moved with the mouse. The user can hence chose which group can have more space on the screen.

Of course, there are `HDividedBox` and `VDividedBox` coming with Halo and the `mx.*` packages.

But nothing with Spark. Moreover, in Flex Builder, `HDividedBox` and `VDividedBox` are not marked as being recommended components.

Are there DividedBox equivalents with Spark?

If not: is it on the roadmap? Are there some cons in using the DividedBox from Halo with my Spark components?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no Spark alternatives for these DividedBox containers. DividedBoxes can use MX and Spark components as children. You can use Divided Boxes without any problems.

Comment: ... or he can create it;s own "slim" divider

Comment: To answer the second question: There's currently no roadmap for additional Spark components. And no, there are no cons in using DividedBox from Halo. BTW: The wiki page [Missing Spark Components](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Missing+Spark+Components) from the Apache Flex project has a good overview of Halo components and their (still missing) Spark equivalents.

Comment: But for Android application no mx controls are supported, so what we do in case of andoid Application ?

Comment: You should consider building TabbedViewNavigatorApplication for mobile.